Trying to use Dev Containers ... IDE Backend keeps re-downloading but never installs
I'm trying to use dev containers feature and I'm having trouble building the container.  When I try to build it, it successfully builds my image and then gets to the step where it is “Downloading the IDE Backend”.  It gets to 99% and then pauses for a while and restarts.  It does this 3-4 times then quits:


Thanks to this comment from
Olga Mulina, show a way to upload IDE Backend installer from local.

download the Linux IDE distribution from this page (it's Linux because the OS in the container is also Linux, we don't support Windows-based containers);
open the Search Everywhere feature in the IDE (double-Shift) and type registry;
enable the devcontainers.use.separate.project.panel key:

after that, on the dev container building process, you should see the following interface:

here you should select the Installation options link and then the Upload installer file action from the dropdown menu.

It save my days, may also save yours.

Hi, we also have a corresponding article in our Knowledge base with practically the same content; you can find it here.
